# error in installing the python packages in caffe installing

Tags: python, gpu, caffe

Im installing caffe using this instructers ([link](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/blob/master/docs/BuildCaffe.md)) and refer to this i use this command for install all of requirments:

```
sudo pip install -r $CAFFE_ROOT/python/requirements.txt
```

but, unfortuantly i got this error:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-
jseAuV/leveldb/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', 
'\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --
record 
/tmp/pip-brJMTP-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-
managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-
jseAuV/leveldb/
```

Im searched for solving this problem , somone said this error will solve by this command:
    pip install --upgrade setuptools
and other commands related to upgrade setuptools ... .

can , anyone help me? 
I use Jetson TX2 GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after search i found that causes this problem is from leveldb library.
leveldb version requirment that wroted ir requirements.txt was leveldb>=0.19,
and according to this github page this version of leveldb not supported my architecture (ARM 64 , aarch64) , but leveldb v1.2 support this architecture , for solving this problem firs i modified requirements.txt leveldb version according this:

```
 leveldb>=0.20
```

then tried installation but unfortunatly it doesnt work.
refer to this page of nvidia , digits couldent be installed on jetson tx2 , but refer to this comment:

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1007431/jetson-tx2/issues-installing-digits-on-tx2/post/5203559/#5203559

my problem solved!
i'm happy (:
by.